# What type of regression model do I use?

Tags: time-series, logistic, bayesian, multiple-regression, signal-detection

$y = \mathbf{X} \beta$ + $\epsilon$ + $m$

Where y, $\epsilon$, and $m$ are $n \times 1$ column vectors, $\beta$ is $p \times 1$ and $\mathbf{X}$ is $n \times p$.

$y$ is a noisy time-series signal modeled by linear combinations of a basis set $\mathbf{X}$ discribed by $\beta$.  $\epsilon$ is additive Gaussian noise.  $m$ is an estimate of the mismatch inherent in the reconstruction.  The columns of $\textbf{X}$ can't perfectly reconstruct $y$, even if it were noiseless.  Am I correct in my understanding that this can be called an errors-in-variables model?

So given y and $\textbf{X}$, what is $\beta$?

Here's the twist:  The true value of $\beta$ should either be 0 or 1, while all other variables are comprised of continuous data.  What I'd like to be able to do is find $\beta$ to be a value between 0 or 1 which corresponds to a probability the corresponding column of $\textbf{X}$ is present in the reconstruction.  A value in $\beta$ of 1 indicates that its corresponding column of x is present, 0 not.

Since the columns of $\textbf{X}$ can't perfectly reconstruct $y$ even if it were noiseless, basic methods like OLS give answers where elements of $\beta$ are above 1 and below 0, which for me are unphysical.

In other words, is there a way to constrain the results of a linear regression ($y = \mathbf{X} \beta + \epsilon + m$) to only admit $\beta$ values between zero and 1 in a way which they can be interpreted as a probability that $\beta$ equals one or not?  Perhaps through the use of a prior distribution?

If anyone has any keywords I can look into, or references to point out, that would be very appreciated!

P.S. If anyone can give a Bayesian interpretation.. Bonus points!  The people this is for love that stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Logistic regression is used when $y$ is binary variable.

Comment: Right.. It just seemed in the ballpark I guess.

Comment: I don't understand how your $\beta$ can be either 0 or 1, can you show some of your data and the way you estimate your parameters. From the details you have provided it seems that you are doing some  basic mistakes.

Comment: It is an odd situation.  What is the protocol for showing data on the site?  I'll try to explain though.  The matrix $\textbf{X}$ are the results from solving an inverse problem on a collection of signals from a simulation.  The parameters of the simulation were defined originally by $\beta$ (columns of a matrix $\textbf{B}$).  The goal is to do parameter estimation on an incident signal y.  Let me know if there is anything else you need to know!  I am just wondering if there is a way to say:  "This column of X is 90% likely to be present in y, and this other column is only 10% etc etc."

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make it clearer. What is matrix $B$?

Comment: Sorry, matrix $\mathbf{B}$ defines the input initial conditions of a simulation (parameters).  Step 1.  Given $\textbf{B}$ and $\textbf{Y}$, find $\textbf{X}$.  $\textbf{XB = Y}$.  I have a solution for this, which is $\mathbf{X}$.  Now, imagine a new signal comes in to a detector, not one of the original columns of $\textbf{Y}$ but a new one y with some noise added.  What are its parameters?  (Find $\beta$ as described).  Is this really a strange situation?  Having prior knowledge that $\beta$ is binary?

Comment: All that other stuff though I think I have worked out pretty solid.  The actual Q is as originally posted.  Thank you for considering the problem though!

Comment: You seem to have things inverted, linguistically.  **X** should be a matrix of variables while **B** is a vector of parameters to be estimated.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I am new to this field and havn't mastered the terminology.  In these comments I am trying to provide background information.  These comments do not further describe the problem I am asking about, which is as stated in the original question.  To perhaps further clarify my original question, is there a way to constrain the results of a linear regression ($y = \mathbf{X} \beta + \epsilon$) to only admit $\beta$ values between zero and 1?  Which can be interpreted as probabilities?

Comment: @PeterRabbit Might I suggest you edit the question to make it a little less confusing? Currently, $\beta$ seems to be referred to as both a parameter and a random variable. Which is it? Second, you state in some places that $\beta$ is constrained to be either 0 or 1, yet in other places that it is constrained to lie between 0 or 1 (the two are obviously VERY different).

Comment: Sorry, I think I have edited to help fix the confusion.  $\beta$ is the solution to the regression problem.  The solution is only "physical" in my case, if its elements can only be either 0 or 1.  Due to the uncertainty in the situation, I am asking if it is possible find a solution which treats $\beta$ as a probability that a column of $\textbf{X}$ is present in $y$.  In that case, it should range between 0 and 1, where if an element of it is say, .9, that could be interpreted as saying that there is a 90% chance that its corresponding column of $\textbf{X}$ is present in the reconstruction.

Comment: From my understanding, treating it this way, means that you are treating it to be a random variable that you are making inferences on.  Sorry for my poor use of terminology.

Comment: You will be more successful in explaining your problem if you try to put it in *your* terms rather than in some abstract mathematical formulation or something else you imagine we're familiar with: that will limit the potential for confusion to *us*, rather than both parties! It sounds rather like you are trying to formulate a PCA rather than a regression problem, but without knowing anything about the problem you're really trying to solve, it's not possible to suggest alternative models.

Comment: >_< OK.  Should I just repost a new Q?  I fear this thread may be going down the drain, and further editing seems to just make this more confusing for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always *force* the $\beta$s to be between 0 and 1 by rewriting the likelihood in terms of $\beta_j = f(\beta^*)$ for some function $f$, e.g. $1/(1+\exp(-\beta^*))$. Then optimise the $\beta^*$s but report the $\beta$s.  However that won't automatically get you an interpretation in terms of the probability that $\beta$ is relevant to the regression.
So I think the first thing to do is  *separate*, conceptually speaking, the question of the probability that each $\beta_j$ is equal to zero i.e. not included/relevant from the value it should take if it is relevant.

As for models, the keywords are probably *Bayesian* and  *automatic relevance determination*.  Assume a Bayesian model with a hierarchical prior such that $p(\beta \mid \alpha) = \prod_j N(0, \alpha_j^{-1})$ and maybe a gamma prior on the $\alpha$s if you're going to sample.  As $\alpha_j$ goes to infinity, $\beta_j$ is more probably equal to zero.
Then integrate out (or optimise) the (ir)relevance parameters $\alpha$ during posterior inference to get predictions for $y$ and separately examine the $\alpha$s to give you an idea which $\beta$s are irrelevant.  For more details on these methods, the references I have to hand are [MacKay (ms)](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/pred.pdf) or [Tipping's work](http://www.miketipping.com/papers.htm), and a tech report by [Minka et al.](http://affect.media.mit.edu/pdfs/04.qi-minka-picard-ghahramani.pdf) discussing fitting stategies.

I've no idea what is your $m$ parameter(s), so I may have missed something to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use simple regression (say OLS), then $\beta$ can be converted to a t-stat, which then can be converted to a p-value, which ranges between $0$ and $1$; a p-value of $0$ for $\beta_i$ means a significant contribution of $X_i$ to $y$, whereas a p-value of 1 means no contribution of $X_i$ to $y$.
Does this help?

Comment: I thought just using OLS or something, but the actual values of $\beta$ _are_ 0 and 1 (From the data set I have). Also when I do that, many times I get negative values for $\beta$, which is not very good for what I'm doing.  I'll look into your suggestion of t-stat -> P-value though, I don't know anything about t-stats and p-values.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know anything about t-stats and p-values then you really need the help of a professional statitician on this project, or take some stats courses (what you are asking is beyond the intro courses) until you have enough knowledge to do this.

Along the way as you are learning (or discussing with a consultant), least squares regression with bounds on the slopes is just a case of quadradic programming and many stats and math programs have routines for doing quadradic programming.

If you want to do this (assuming "this" is well defined) using Bayesian methods then it is pretty straight forward, just choose priors that limit your parameters to the range desired (uniform or beta priors, possibly discrete priors).

You may also want to look at model averaging or Bayesian model averaging, these can give answers of the probability of an x variable being a predictor of the y variable.

We need to understand the problem better (and you need to understand the statistical modeling better) in order to give more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not an errors in variables problem. That would refer to noise in the INDEPENDENT variables, i.e., X.

Your problem is a bound constrained OLS problem, where the variables are constrained to lie in the closed interval [0,1]. Can you truly interpret these numbers as probabilities? That seems a stretch, if you use a least squares in any form to do the estimation. The numbers are then simply linear combinations of the independent variables, NOT probabilities.

For the numbers to make sense as probabilities, you would arguably need to do some variety of maximum likelihood estimation. Of course, you can always feel free to interpret a number in any way you want, but if you want a meaningful result, it is best to use statistics properly. For that to work, you need to clearly define what it means for a column to be part of the model. A linear combination is NOT a probability.